# Change a form value before submit without changing the shown value

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm working on a login website with PHP and Javascript.
But before submitting the username and the password, the password has to be encrypted.

To do so, I use the following code (Please don't mind the get method, it's normal) :

```
<form name="myForm" action="home" method="get">
      <div class="form-group pb-3 pt-0">
        <label for="password"><?= $content['MyAvatarConnexion']['password'] ?></label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control"
          placeholder="<?= $content['MyAvatarConnexion']['inputPassword'] ?>">
      </div>        
</form>
```

And I add a listener which call the encrypter, which works with a Promise.

```
<script>
const form = document.forms["myForm"];
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    function callback(encryptstring){form.password.value = encryptstring; form.submit(); }
    var encrypter = new Encrypter(form.password.value, callback);
  });
</script>
```

The change is working however, when I click on the submit button and before the page is changing, I can see that the typied password in switching from the clear password to the encrypted password.

I have tried to put `form.password.hidden = true;` but it changes all the page layout before changing the page which is not quitte aesthetic.

How can I change the value without changing the shown value ?

Comment: You can use a hidden field and set the value of that instead original password filed.

Comment: Why bother encrypting on the client? Your web site should be using SSL, so hash the password on the server with [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) before storing it, and check it later with [password_verfiy()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: Plus one to the above, but as a side note, I wouldn't try to do a role your own authentication system unless you're using it as a learning tool. There are plenty of tried & tested authentication libraries, or frameworks with this built in.

Comment: @mohitjain I will do as you say. I have though about this but I don't know if there is any other way, because I though it would be a lot for a quitte small issue. Thanks for your reponse.

Comment: @JamesGlendenning & TangentiallyPerpendicular Actually, I don't know why the encrypting is on the client side. I will ask to my internship tutor.

Comment: The one reason to encrypt client-side _in this very specific example_ is because of the GET request which would cause the password to be written to standard log files. However, the solution pretty much everyone would recommend is to switch to POST, not encrypt in JS.